# Python UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, urllib

I am building a little website crawler and I've encountered some problems with it. The first one would be Unicode characters in the url

Let's say I have the following url : http://putlocker.is/actor/Juan_Fern%C3%A1ndez

My code is :

```
        try:

             connection = urllib.urlopen(self.__link)
             get = connection.read().decode('utf8')


        except:
            if UnicodeDecodeError:
                 print("UnicodeDecodeError !!!")
```

I'm talkink about the original link , not about the encoded one

Comment: Can't reproduce it with given URL. I've tried urllib, urllib2 and requests - no UnicodeError.

Comment: The error comes from the ORIGINAL link  with the original characters . Please enter the website and copy the link from there

Comment: As I understand you need to decode content of the page the link is referring to. What I did is followed the linked and copied it from address bar. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: If you want people to use the original link, use the original link in your question; you're just inviting confusion. And if you're getting an error, pasting the full error into the question is better than making us guess.

Comment: The problem is that if I copy the original link it becomes automatically http://putlocker.is/actor/Juan_Fern%C3%A1ndez this link !!

Comment: Can you please remove `try-except` and provide output of your program then? Cause I can not understand where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of error handling seems to be wrong. Expression under your if-statement `UnicodeDecodeError` will always be True. You probably should change it to

```
try:
    ...
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    #handle error
```

In your case any error is just swallowed so you don't even see what the actual error is.

Comment: It wouldn't explain why his except-clause gets executed though. Then again, OP didn't show his full code.

Comment: Yes, it's probably some other error cause there is no problem decoding content of that link to utf-8

Comment: Yep sorry , let's say self.__link is the link I have provided in the original form